# Runtime error loading Interface definition in Java using Apache HTTP library

Tags: java, jar, apache-httpclient-4.x

I am attempting to make a simple wrapper around an API connection in Java. I am using the `org.apache.http` library to do this.

I have downloaded the following jar files:

- [org.apache.http httpclient](http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpclient/4.5.1/httpclient-4.5.1.jar) saved as `./org.apache.httpclient.jar`
- [org.apache.http httpcore](http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpcore/4.4.4/httpcore-4.4.4.jar) saved as `./org.apache.httpcore.jar`

I can then successfully compile the file with:

```
$ javac -cp "./org.apache.httpclient.jar:./org.apache.httpcore.jar" Api.java
```

However when running it with `$ java Api` I receive:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/http/HttpEntity
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2625)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:2866)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1676)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.getMainMethod(LauncherHelper.java:494)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:486)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.http.HttpEntity
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    ... 6 more
```

*[It turned out the issue was with how code was being run after compilation; the code has been removed to avoid distracting from the actual problem and solution]*

I can't see why the system has a problem finding the `HttpEntity` interface when it finds other imports successfully, and can compile. If I remove any of the `import` lines compilation fails with unknown symbol errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

-cp should contain the directory where you classes are, for example:

```
java -cp "./org.apache.httpclient.jar:./org.apache.httpcore.jar:." Api
```

Assuming that your `Api.class` is in the current directory. (replace : by ; as classpath separator if your are on a windows system)

Comment: Thanks, this solved it; I was missing the "." as part of the classpath when attempting to use the other solution.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried running the java with '-classpath'. While compiling you are giving the classpath, so you need to add the classpath option for running the class file as well.

More details can be found at below link:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/classpath.html

Also you can print which libs are in classpath using below command.

```
java -cp $(for i in lib/*.jar ; do echo -n $i: ; done). com.test.Class
```

Comment: Adding the same `-cp ""` argument before the class name tells me it could not load the main class. Is that a new bug or am I running it incorrectly?

Comment: java -cp .:lib/* my.main.Class

Comment: Unfortunately that's still not working. My class file is just "Api.class"; does it need to be namespaced to run?

Comment: Yes..Can you keep the jars in a folder like 'lib' and run  like - java -cp .:lib/* my.main.Class and check. You can also try by remove the ./, go to jar directory java -cp "org.apache.httpclient.jar:org.apache.httpcore.jar" my.package.Api

Comment: I've now moved them into a `lib/` directory; the problem was that I wasn't including `.` in the classpath when running - it isn't needed for compile but is for running.

Comment: I remember I had the issue once when I initially started working on linux and stuck for some hours...glad you found the solution